# Emitting a Qt::signal from worker thread makes the UI update on main thread by default?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml, signals-slots

I am new to `Qt`. I have worker thread that is an `std::thread`. The worker thread function continuously fetches some some data in a loop. The size of the data is frequently updated on a `Text` element on a `QML` UI. I have a listener callback which is nothing but an `std::function` and it gets called from the `thread's function`. It sends me callbacks based on which I updated the `Text` element on `QML`. I update it using `signal slot` mechanism.

Following is the `QML : Text` element:

```
Text {
  id: mytext
  objectName: "mytextobject"

  function slotUpdateData(someValue){
    mytext = someValue
  }
}
```

`SignalUpdateData` is connected with `slotUpdateData` which resides on `QML` side. Every time I get the data event callback from the `std::thread`, I `emit SignalUpdateData` which updates the `QML Text element` on `UI`.

```
void CallBackReceivedFromWorkerThread(float someValue) {
  emit SignalUpdateData(someValue)
}
```

Following is how I have connected this `C++ signal` with the `QML slot`

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(SignalUpdateData(QVariant)), myTextItemQObject, SLOT(slotUpdateData(QVariant)));
```

**And all of this works fine. No crashes, lock-ups, nothing.**

As per my understanding, since the worker thread's function is triggering the callback, the execution control is on the worker thread when the callback is received. So when doing `emit SignalUpdateData(someValue)`, we'er still on the worker thread. **And as far as I know from my previous experience in `android` & `java`, we cannot update the UI from anywhere outside the `main thread` of the application.**

So, *How is this working ? Is `emit SignalUpdateData(someValue)` putting the call into the `main UI thread's event loop` ? Is `Qt` still making the UI change on `main thread` in spite of me calling for it from a `worker thread` ? If my approach is fine, then does it have performance implications ? What is the best recommendation to do this ?*

*I want to be very sure about this & not just lucky about making this to work. Should I use a [Qt::Connection_enum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) as well for best approach ?*

Comment: As far as I know (may be wrong), everything QML happens on the main/gui thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're leveraging Qt the way it was meant to be! And you've run into it accidentally: that's a sign of a decent design - it "just works". Hooray for you, hooray for Qt :)

It's working because Qt has been designed specifically to make it work, and you're using the default automatic connection whose raison d'être is to help you out in this specific case. So you happen to be doing everything right: change nothing!

When you emit a signal, Qt acquires relevant source and destination object mutexes, and compares the receiving object's `thread()` to `QThread::currentThread()`. If they are identical, the slot/functor is called immediately: it happens in the body of the signal, so the slot is called before the signal returns. This is safe as the target object is used from its `thread()`, where it's safe.

If `target->thread() != QThread::currentThread()`, then a `QMetaCallEvent` is queued to the target object. The event contains the (equivalent of) slot method pointer and a copy of any parameters passed by the slot. The `QObject::event` implementation handles the event and executes the call. The target object thread's event loop is on the call stack, since its job is to deliver the queued events to the object.

The above is, in a nutshell the meaning of a `Qt::AutoConnection`. If you're using `Qt::QueuedConnection`, the 2nd case applies no matter what the threads are. If you're using `Qt::DirectConnection`, the 1st case applies no matter what.

My guess is that >95% of the uses of a non-automatic connection type in Qt-related questions on SO are unnecessary and stem from lack of understanding and resorting to what amounts to magic incantations.

Comment: Could you also point out, by and large, where these things are implemented in Qt's source code?

Comment: @Paul It's in the implementation of [`QObject`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/) for the most part, and of course it cooperates with the metadata system.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Kuba Ober . Its really great that Qt takes over this responsibility of running on the main thread when required. I always felt it to be too much to ask from a developer if I have to worry about making sure that my update call on the UI has to ensured to be called UI thread by myself. This is really great news. I doubted that this might be the case. hence, tried the signal slot mechanism. Awesome... Qt rocks !!

Comment: @SegmentationFault It gets better: the target can be any thread with an event loop, not just the UI thread is. E.g. if you emit a signal in the UI thread, and the slot is in a worker thread, things will work too :) And the emitting thread can truly be any thread: it doesn't have to be created using `QThread` at all. It can be a worker thread created by a 3rd-party C library written in 1998, a library that you've supplied a callback function to - said callback emitting a signal. It's a means of escaping the thread jail you might find yourself in.

Comment: @KubaOber This is really great news for me. Qt is champion to handle this so elegantly. Its such a problem in other frameworks